# Remap key on MacBook with KeyRemap4MacBook. change 'CMD+C' to 'CMD+M'

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook, macbook-pro, remapping

I want to remap keys on a MacBook with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en).

I need to change <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, because I don't like to always use left hand to press copy&plaste, it's aching and feeling bad.

I want to copy & plaste with right hand. following script does not work at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <root>
  <item>
  <name>Copy & Plaste</name>
  <appendix>Change cmd+C to cmd+M</appendix>
  <identifier>private.mead_copy_remap</identifier>
  <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::C, VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::M</autogen>
 </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Finally, I solve it without any other software kit. System-Pref, keyboard, application-shortcut....wow...

Answer (score 1):

The private.xml worked for me, but it just made pressing command-C insert `m`. Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Copy & Paste</name>
        <appendix></appendix>
        <identifier>private.mead_copy_remap</identifier>
        <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::M, VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::C, VK_COMMAND</autogen>
        <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::N, VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::V, VK_COMMAND</autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

Remember to press the ReloadXML button and enable the remapping:

[image]